# Find a directory created today

Tags: find, directory, timestamps

How can I find a directory whose name starts with `cy` and that was created today?

Comment: what do you mean by `based on today's date`

Comment: @ Networker i wanna find directory with name `cy` which is created today

Answer (score 1):

```
$ TODAY="cy`date '+%Y%m%d'`"
$ find / -name $TODAY
```

To see the contents of $TODAY:

```
$ echo $TODAY
$ cy20140806
```

If you just want it in YYMMDD format, then:

```
$ TODAY="cy`date '+%y%m%d'`"
$ find / -name $TODAY

$ echo $TODAY
$ cy140806
```

This works for me on Solaris 10. On your system, it may be different. Run a `man date` to see the options for your system.

Answer (score 1):

for the last 24 hours

```
find wherever -name cy\* -ctime -1 -print
```

If there is no file begining witch cy in wherever, you may avoid backslashig *.

since midnight

```
find wherever -daystart -name cy\* -ctime -1 -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have clarified your question, here is an answer that should meet your clarified question:

```
touch -t `date +%m%d0000` /tmp/midnight
find / -type d -newer /tmp/$$ -name cy
rm /tmp/midnight
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -newerct ` date +"%D"` -name cy
```

This find cy that was changed (or created) after midnight.

the newerXY params:

c = change time of the file(you can also try 'B', for birth time but it's not supported on all platforms)

t = date format to compare with. Very flexible :)

try `man find` for more information about newerXY